# I am aware its not possible. Hypothetically How would you stop? if You find yourself in a spaceship travelling at almost the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, time-dilation

assumptions made :

1. Somehow you find yourself travelling at almost the speed of light.
2. No other external force is acting on you and you are travelling in the same direction.

> *I mean, How would you decelerate?*

---

and even if you find a way to decelerate,

> *Won't the space ship reach the end of The Universe in the direction
>   you are travelling before you could perform any action to slow down
>   the space ship because of time dilation?* if The Universe has an end that is,

---

The dilema im facing here is:

to my knowledge,

1. Time slows down as you approach light speed.
2. Universe has no end.

Because the universe is never ending, I assume that even if there is a hypothetical button to stop the spaceship You can't press the button because time is literally paused since you are travelling at almost the light speed and You will keep moving in the same direction unless acted upon by an external force.

**Is my assumption correct? 
please correct me if I'm wrong.**

Comment: What makes you think you are *not* traveling very close to the speed of light right now, in some reference frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Somehow you find yourself travelling in the speed of light.

Unfortunately, nothing can travel at the speed of light. That assumption alone makes your question unanswerable because we are now breaking the laws of physics and making up another world than the one we actually live in. How the physics of that world works, is not something anyone would know.

But, we could ask the same question while moving *very* fast, although below the speed of light.

> I mean, How would you decelerate?

Ignoring the speed-of-light assumption-issue, then I presume you could slow down your spaceship as you would be able to do at any other speed. That is, turn on your backwards-thrusters, your braking engines. Basically, throw something forwards (such as fuel exhaust), and then you will - due to the law of momentum conservation - slow down yourself.

> Won't the space ship reach the end of The Universe in the direction you are travelling [...] if The Universe has an end that is,

Well, possibly you will fly "over the edge" of the Universe - *assuming there is such an edge*. But if there is an edge, wouldn't whatever is beyond that edge also
have to be a part of the universe? The universe is after all our term for *everything*.

Nevertheless, we are dealing with something we do not know here.

> [...] before you could perform any action to slow down the space ship because of time dilation?
>
> You can't press the button because time is literally paused since you are travelling at almost the light speed

No, this does not make much sense. When you travel fast, you are not slowed down in your actions. You can still move around as freely and as fast as before. It will look slower when viewed by someone who is *not* moving fast, but it will not be slower to you.

The only way I can make sense of this question is if you are asking if you will reach the universe's end *of time* (not reaching the edge of space, but the end of time when the universe ceases to exist) before managing to push the stop button on the spacecraft. But whether or not the universe will ever end, imploding or so, or continuing to expand infinitely, is [again something we do not know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultimate_fate_of_the_universe).

Comment: "if the universe will end of time before we manage to push the stop button on the spacecraft." Yes I was trying to convey that. My bad, I'll rephrase that part.

Comment: @PrashanShan I have rephrased that sentence.

Answer (score 4):

> Somehow you find yourself travelling in the speed of light.

This already rules out any answer within the bounds of mainstream physics. It is simply a nonsensical premise, akin to saying "somehow you find yourself further north than the north pole."

It is common for laypeople and beginning students to hear "you cannot travel faster than $c$" and think that it means that there is simply a vague rule against it, as though it were carved on a stone tablet and [carried down a mountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments).  But this is not the case.  It simply *does not make sense* for an observer to have a speed greater than or equal to $c$.

To assume that an observer travels with speed $c$ is to assume that relativity itself is to be thrown in the bin.  If you want to do that, then fine - there are no laws against ignoring mainstream physics - but if you then ask "what would happen," you need to come up with something which replaces the physics that you've already decided to throw away.  Without doing so, there is no way to answer the question.